# geom_contour with Lambert projection

Tags: r, r-sf

I'm trying to plot a map of the Northeast Atlantic, with specific isobaths highlighted. Given the area, I'd prefer to use the LAEA projection. However, this seems to cause geom_contour to fail.

Here is the background  code:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(marmap)
library(rnaturalearth)

#Set boundaries
bbox <- tibble(x = c(-20, 10), y = c(45, 60))
#Add coordinates converted to LAEA 
bbox <- bbox %>%
      bind_cols(bbox %>% 
                  st_as_sf(coords = c("x", "y")) %>%
                  st_set_crs(4326) %>% #current CRS is WSG84
                  st_transform(3035) %>% #transform CRS to 3035 (Lambert)
                  mutate(x_laea = unlist(map(geometry, 1)),
                         y_laea = unlist(map(geometry, 2))) %>%
                  st_set_geometry(NULL))

#Extract bathymetry for area of interest
nea <- fortify.bathy(getNOAA.bathy(lon1 = min(bbox$x), 
                                   lon2 = max(bbox$x),
                                   lat1 = min(bbox$y), 
                                   lat2 = max(bbox$y), 
                                   resolution = 5))
```

This works nicely:

```
ggplot() +
  geom_sf(data = ne_countries(scale = "medium", 
                              returnclass = "sf")) +
  geom_contour(data = nea,
               aes(x = x, 
                   y = y, 
                   z = z),
               breaks = c(-600)) +
  coord_sf(xlim = c(min(bbox$x), 
                    max(bbox$x)),
           ylim = c(min(bbox$y), 
                    max(bbox$y)))
```

But this does not (only the country layer shows up, not the `nea` one):

```
ggplot() +
  geom_sf(data = ne_countries(scale = "medium", 
                              returnclass = "sf")) +
  geom_contour(data = nea,
               aes(x = x, 
                   y = y, 
                   z = z)) +
  coord_sf(crs = 3035,
           xlim = c(min(bbox$x_laea), 
                    max(bbox$x_laea)),
           ylim = c(min(bbox$y_laea), 
                    max(bbox$y_laea)))
```

Even if I first convert `nae` to LAEA first:

```
nea_laea <- nea %>% 
  st_as_sf(coords = c("x", "y")) %>%
  st_set_crs(4326) %>% #current CRS is WSG84
  st_transform(3035) %>% #transform CRS to 3035 (Lambert)
  mutate(x = unlist(map(geometry, 1)),
         y = unlist(map(geometry, 2))) %>%
  st_set_geometry(NULL)
ggplot() +
  geom_sf(data = ne_countries(scale = "medium", 
                              returnclass = "sf")) +
  geom_contour(data = nea_laea,
               aes(x = x, 
                   y = y, 
                   z = z)) +
  coord_sf(crs = 3035,
           xlim = c(min(bbox$x_laea), 
                    max(bbox$x_laea)),
           ylim = c(min(bbox$y_laea), 
                    max(bbox$y_laea)))
```

I've looked for solutions and figured that a nice way would be to extract the underlying data from the non-reprojected contour, and then plot them with the LAEA projection as geom_line:

```
extracted_data <- ggplot_build(ggplot() +
                                 geom_contour(data = nea,
                                              aes(x = x, y = y, z = z),
                                              breaks = c(-600)))$data[[1]] %>% 
  st_as_sf(coords = c("x", "y")) %>%
  st_set_crs(4326) %>% #current CRS is WSG84
  st_transform(3035) %>% #transform CRS to 3035 (Lambert)
  mutate(x = unlist(map(geometry, 1)),
         y = unlist(map(geometry, 2))) %>%
  st_set_geometry(NULL)
```

This *almost* works, except that it seems the points are not ordered well, so the resulting plot is all scrambled:

```
ggplot() +
  geom_sf(data = ne_countries(scale = "medium", 
                              returnclass = "sf")) +
  geom_line(data = extracted_data,
            aes(x = x, 
                y = y, 
                group = group)) +
  coord_sf(crs = 3035,
           xlim = c(min(bbox$x_laea), 
                    max(bbox$x_laea)),
           ylim = c(min(bbox$y_laea), 
                    max(bbox$y_laea)))
```

Any idea how to fix this?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: What does "this does not [work nicely]" mean here? Error messages? Can you show the output it produces?

Comment: I've edited my post. I mean that the bathymetry layer does not show up, which seems to make sense given Spacedman's post below...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another solution is to use the following approach:

1. Set the bounding box without projection (WGS84 -> crs = 4326) and project the bounding box in Lambert (with `sf::st_transform()`)
2. Download bathymetric data and project in Lambert with `marmap` and `raster` functions
3. Download country data and project in Lambert (with `sf::st_transform()`)
4. plot using `ggplot2` and `sf`.

This approach has the advantage that all your data layers are projected in Lambert. Hence, you can use the full potential of `ggplot2` and `sf` for plotting. More specifically, you can use `geom_tile()`, and as many `geom_contour()` layers as you need. If you want to draw several contour lines, you don't have to compute them individually: all you have to do is add the isoline value in the `breaks` argument of `geom_contour()`.

Here is an example with your coordinates and the -600m isobath:

```
# Load useful packages
library(sf)
library(marmap)
library(tidyverse)
library(rnaturalearth)

# Set Lambert projection
proj = 3035

# Set bounding box (WGS 84)
min_lon <- -20
max_lon <- 10
min_lat <- 45
max_lat <- 60

# Project bbox
bbox <- st_sfc(st_point(c(min_lon, min_lat)), 
               st_point(c(max_lon, max_lat)), 
               crs = 4326)
bbox_proj <- st_coordinates(st_transform(bbox, crs = proj))

# Get bathymetric data
bathy <- getNOAA.bathy(lon1 = min_lon, lon2 = max_lon,
                       lat1 = min_lat, lat2 = max_lat,
                       resolution = 5, keep = TRUE)

# Project bathymetric data and transform to plot with ggplot2
proj_bathy <- as.raster(bathy) %>% 
  raster::projectRaster(crs = proj) %>% 
  as.bathy() %>% 
  as.xyz()

# Import country data and project
country <- ne_countries(scale = "medium", returnclass = "sf")
country_proj <- st_transform(country, crs = proj)

# Plot using ggplot and sf
ggplot() + 
  geom_sf(data = country_proj) +
  geom_contour(data = proj_bathy, 
               aes(x = V1, y = V2, z = V3),
               breaks = -600, color = "red") +
  coord_sf(xlim = bbox_proj[,'X'], 
           ylim = bbox_proj[,'Y']) +
  labs(x = "Longitude", y = "Latitude") +
  theme_minimal()
```

And the plot produced:

[image]

Comment: Thank you Benoit, this is a great alternative. More flexible indeed.

Answer (score 3):

Once you've projected your points to something other than the regular lat-long grid, you can't do a contour using `geom_contour` without re-interpolating onto a regular grid. `help(geom_contour)` explains:

```
Description:

     ggplot2 can not draw true 3D surfaces, but you can use
     ‘geom_contour()’, ‘geom_contour_filled()’, and ‘geom_tile()’ to
     visualise 3D surfaces in 2D. To specify a valid surface, the data
     must contain ‘x’, ‘y’, and ‘z’ coordinates, and each unique
     combination of ‘x’ and ‘y’ can appear at most once. Contouring
     requires that the points can be rearranged so that the ‘z’ values
     form a matrix, with rows corresponding to unique ‘x’ values, and
     columns corresponding to unique ‘y’ values. Missing entries are
     allowed, but contouring will only be done on cells of the grid
     with all four ‘z’ values present. If your data is irregular, you
     can interpolate to a grid before visualising using the
     ‘interp::interp()’ function from the ‘interp’ package (or one of
     the interpolating functions from the ‘akima’ package.)
```

I had trouble understanding what your code was trying to do in places - you can make it more tidy by removing some of the tidyverse stuff. This:

```
> bbox %>% select(y_laea) %>% filter(y_laea == min(y_laea)) %>% pull()
[1] 2904046
```

is equivalent to this:

```
> min(bbox$y_laea)
[1] 2904046
```

and similarly for the max and X coords.

If all you want to do is get a particular contour set, use `contourLines` instead of trying to get values out of a plotting construct. Here's a complete example, I've tried to make this as simple as possible so it only uses `sf` and `marmap`:

Use these packages:

```
library(sf)
library(marmap)
```

set limits - we're not going to transform these so no point building a data frame with them. It also simplified extracting limits:

```
xr=c(-20, 10)
yr=c(45,60)
```

Get bathymetry as a matrix - do not "fortify" it:

```
bathy <- getNOAA.bathy(lon1 = min(xr), 
                     lon2 = max(xr),
                     lat1 = min(yr),
                     lat2 = max(yr),
                     resolution = 5)
```

Now get the lat and lon coords from the dimnames. See `marmap::as.xyz` for where I got this from:

```
lon = as.numeric(rownames(bathy))
lat = as.numeric(colnames(bathy))
```

Now we have a matrix and coordinates so we can feed this to `contourLines` and get the -600 level:

```
c600_list = contourLines(x=lon, y=lat, z=bathy, levels=-600)
```

This is a list of elements with `$x` and `$y` components, so we loop over them with `lapply` and build `st_linestring` objects, then join that list of geometry primitives using `st_sfc`:

```
c600 = do.call(st_sfc,
             lapply(c600_list, function(l){st_linestring(cbind(l$x, l$y))}) 
             )
```

So far everything has been lat-long epsg:4326 so let's set that:

```
st_crs(c600) = 4326
```

and now we can convert to LAEA epsg:3035:

```
c600_laea = st_transform(c600, 3035)
```

You can use `ggplot2` to plot:

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot() + geom_sf(data=c600_laea)
```

[image]

or use the `tmap` package in interactive mode to get some context and make sure we're in the right place:

```
library(tmap)
tmap_mode("view")
# tmap mode set to interactive viewing
tm_shape(c600_laea) + tm_lines()
```

[image]

Comment: I've edited my post.
OK... this is annoying, as I'd prefer not to re-interpolate the data (which is why I wanted to extract geom_contour's data to then plot them as a regular geom_line... I'll look into the `interp` and `akima` packages if need be. Thanks for your answer

Comment: Is all you care about getting the specific -600 contour in LAEA projection? Not necessarily mapping the whole thing in that coordinate system?

Comment: Yes, I just want that specific contour in LAEA projection.

Comment: Have added code to do this with `contourLines`. The line might be slightly different to what ggplot shows but these things have to be approximate given the gridded nature of the source data.